# Find value in Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a task in javascript. I want to extract the value from an array in an API. I want to get the last_price in the Monet_ADA array. Here is the data in the API.

641f0571d02b45b868ac1c479fc8118c5be6744ec3d2c5e13bd888b6.ZOMBIE_ADA: {last_price: 0.0016, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
682fe60c9918842b3323c43b5144bc3d52a23bd2fb81345560d73f63.NEWM_ADA: {last_price: 2.4e-8, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
722c45e8ba2a3c399cf09949abe74546ecb75defb8206914085dc28e.CDX_ADA: {last_price: 0.22, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
776da8416dc56107275424b009eb82353235f10ef8e0b77088fd7964.TrustCoin_ADA: {last_price: 0.00006, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
**782c158a98aed3aa676d9c85117525dcf3acc5506a30a8d87369fbcb.Monet_ADA:** {last_price: 1.1e-9, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
804f5544c1962a40546827cab750a88404dc7108c0f588b72964754f.VYFI_ADA: {last_price: 0.0000019, base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
815f432f5d9b36e77989d0fea374292e9c8330c5146ca8500632b3cf.Squid_ADA: {last_price: 'NA', base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
823f7c8e25ee35f368daf2c9b6b4783c1d9a763eb5227b50b095f6c2.Djedi_ADA: {last_price: 'NA', base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}
0864aa509385d78b9d83e8547424a055bb93e152a767383c6e0ea854.AINU_ADA: {last_price: 'NA', base_volume: 0, quote_volume: 0}

Here is my code:

```
const api_url = 'http://analytics.muesliswap.com/ticker';
    
     async function getMonetPrice(){
        const response = await fetch (api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
    
    getMonetPrice();
```

My code doesn't throw an error, it just returns all the data in the API. I need help parsing through the data and then returning just the last_price value in the Monet.ADA array. Please and thank you.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? You are logging the entire response. Does it throw an error? Does it return something other than the expected value?

Comment: Please add a sample of the data, rather than a screenshot so that answers can provide a solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear exactly what you need but hope this helps.

```js
const api_url = 'http://analytics.muesliswap.com/ticker';

    async function getMonetPrice() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(
            data[Object.keys(data).find((key) => key.endsWith('Monet_ADA'))]
                .last_price
        );
    }

    getMonetPrice();
```

Comment: @Murray this won't work if the UUID of that key changes.

Comment: @Andy you are right my bad will edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
const apiURL = 'http://analytics.muesliswap.com/ticker';

// Returns false on failure, or price on success
const getMonetPrice = async (apiURL) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        const { '782c158a98aed3aa676d9c85117525dcf3acc5506a30a8d87369fbcb.Monet_ADA': monetPrice } = await response.json();
        if (!monetPrice) {
            throw "Couldn't find monetPrice";
            return;
        }

        const { last_price } = monetPrice;
        if (!last_price) {
            throw "Couldn't find last_price";
            return;
        }
        
        return last_price;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
};
    
const run = async () => {
    const monetPrice = await getMonetPrice(apiURL);
    console.log('monetPrice', monetPrice);
};

run();
```

Comment: Hi Ron, your code works well when I run it locally through visual studio code. But when I embed it into my webflow site, it returns 'false'. Any idea why?

Comment: Add console.log(error) to the catch block and see what is the case. The mometPrice property might be a bit different cause it's a like HASH.Monet_ADA.
If so, you can iterate the response.json() and find it by key ending with ".Monet_ADA".

If you need help with this, I can edit the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is an object with obscure keys, one of them ending in a string that the OP aims to get at.  First find the key...

```
const key = Object.keys(data).find(k => k.endsWith('Monet_ADA'));
const lastPrice = key ? data[key].last_price : null;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the correct method. Your other option if you don't care about the GUIDs prepending each key is to strip all of them (substring the key on `.` and take the second index), then you can access the data with just `Monet_ADA`.

Comment: Agree, @JeffB, I'm surprised the OP seems to prefer a big, hard-coded key in the code.

Comment: For future people who could see this, it is important to know that hard coding a key with a GUID is not a good thing. Mainly because GUIDs change. All the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's an object, not an array, but you can still [iterate over it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).
2. Extract the key/value from each [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries), and check to see if the key [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) "Monet_ADA".

In this example I'm passing in an endpoint, and a query object, to make life a little easier.

```js
// Get the data
function getData(endpoint) {
  return fetch(endpoint);
}

// Accept the data, and a query object
function finder(data, { type, prop }) {

  // Iterate over the object entries and get the
  // key/value from each
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {

    // If the key ends with the query type
    // return the query prop value
    if (key.endsWith(type)) return value[prop];
  }

  // Otherwise return a default message
  return 'No value available';

}

// Accept an endpoint, and a query object,
// get the data, and parse it. Then call `finder`
// with the data, and the query
async function main(endpoint, query) {
  const response = await getData(endpoint);
  const data = await response.json();
  const lastPrice = await finder(data, query);
  console.log(lastPrice);
}

const endpoint = 'https://analytics.muesliswap.com/ticker';
const query = { type: 'Monet_ADA', prop: 'last_price' };

main(endpoint, query);
```